# FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp and FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessagenot working in firebase messaging flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase messaging with local notifications but `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` and `FirebaseMessaging.instance .getInitialMessage` is not working as I want to open the app on notification click.
Here is my code:

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  log("onMessageOpenedApp is fired");
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  LoginStorage storage = LoginStorage();
  log("storage.getIsLogin() = ${storage.getIsLogin()}");
  if (storage.getIsLogin() == "true") {
    Get.off(() => ChatPage(
          roomId: message.data["room_id"],
          roomName: message.data["roomname"],
          totalMsgs: "0",
          roomType: message.data["room_type"],
        ));
  } else {
    Get.off(() => LoginPage());
  }
  log('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the perfect code, but this issue is not about the code. This happened because your app is in foreground when you fire the notification,
the app needs to be terminated or in the background at this time.

**Also add following code it help when your app have a fresh start**

```
   FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage message) {
       //Navigate Here
    });
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message){
    if(message!=null){
      log("onMessageOpenedApp is fired");
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  LoginStorage storage = LoginStorage();
  log("storage.getIsLogin() = ${storage.getIsLogin()}");
  if (storage.getIsLogin() == "true") {
    Get.off(() => ChatPage(
          roomId: message.data["room_id"],
          roomName: message.data["roomname"],
          totalMsgs: "0",
          roomType: message.data["room_type"],
        ));
  } else {
    Get.off(() => LoginPage());
  }
  log('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
    }
 });
```

Comment: This methods works on background notification click? I used but same issue. This method does not fire on notification click.

Comment: Then may be you are getting some exception, put all code of listen method inside try catch block and debug it, you need to minimize your app then you can debug while clicking on notification.

Comment: I have tried but no any exception. I think nothing is working for background notification.

Comment: await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();, what does this line does,try commenting this

Comment: this is for dismissing the notification. Removing it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() and FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen work fine with iOS.
For Android I found another solution.

First in method to show push notification add reader of a payload.

```
void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
            // one that already exists in example app.
            icon: 'launch_background',
          ),
        ),
        // Add reading of a payload based on the contents of notification
        // In my case:
        payload: notification.data['params']);
  }
}
```

Then somewhere in the application for example in initState method try to call the payload.

```
NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    if (notificationAppLaunchDetails != null && notificationAppLaunchDetails.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
      var payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails.notificationResponse?.payload;
      if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
        // Your code to handle the payload for routing.
      }
    }
```

Be aware that flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin is properly initialized in main().